# How to sort particular colum rows in datatable

Tags: c#-4.0, sorting, datatable

I have a DataTable like this

```
     Name     Age

     Raj      20
     Biny     19
     Raj      17
     Jose     27
     Jose     15
```

When I click `Name` Column, then I should get the datatable sorted as

```
       Name     Age

      Biny     19        
      Jose     15
      Jose     27
      Raj      17
      Raj      20
```

The above table is sorted Based on Name column. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something of this kind should work for you.

```
dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Name asc";
```

Also you can create a method to change the ascending/descending behavior of dofferent columns by taking them as arguments. Only challenge you will have to recognize is which column header is clicked. That should not be that difficult.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that select will do the trick. It has a sorting option

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem is by making a stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_<procedure_name>]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Err int

SELECT [Name], [Age]
FROM [Table_Name]
ORDER BY Name ASC
SET @Err = @@Error

RETURN @Err
END
```

call this stored procedure

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

}